# Cannot communicate from VM instance in Google compute

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are using Google compute engine with a Gateway VM having public IP and couple of other VM's with private IP to host our test and production environment. All of them are running on Debian distribution of linux.

All incoming and outgoing connections were working fine until couple of days ago. From last two days calls to the same domain names are failing. Let's say, www.xyz.com is hosted in one of our VM; when the VM makes call to other websites (e.g., www.google.com) it's working fine, but when it's trying to make call to www.xyz.com, it's getting a gateway timeout.

Although we didn't do any recent changes in the firewall configuration, we're having this strange issue of gateway timeout for the calls to same domain. I am suspecting that it could be because of some new firewall rule of google compute engine.

Comment: Are you still encountering any issues?

Comment: Yes, the issue is still there. However, we've changed our application code so that all calls to self domain goes to localhost.